# check exist all value every single key in array?

Tags: php

i have an $arrays array like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => VUM
        [1] => UA0885
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => VUA
        [1] => UA0885
    )
```

)

i want to check if input value exist (VUA & UA0885), than not add it to this array. 
Ex:

```
(VUA & UA0885) => not add
(VUB & UA0885) => add
(VUA & UA0886) => add
```

here is my code:

```
foreach($arrays as $array){
    if($array[0] != $_REQUEST['tourcode'] || $array[1] != $_REQUEST['promocode']){
    $arrays[] = array($_REQUEST['tourcode'],$_REQUEST['promocode']);
    }

}
```

Tried use in_array too but it still add a duplicate to $arrays

Comment: why are you pushing the array into the main array`$arrays[] = array($_REQUEST['tourcode'],$_REQUEST['promocode']);` ?

Comment: Change this to `$arrays[]` this `$result[]`, so that you can get your desired output in `$result`

Comment: The if statement is correct, check the above comments

Comment: @AgamBanga i want to make an array incluce (tourcode,promocode) and change it to json use json_encode

Comment: Did you search for values or did you search for [var1, var2] array using in_array?

Comment: the issue is with the logic, you are testing each array separately, and adding if values don't correspond to one array. What you want is add it if it corresponds to none of them. To achieve this, i suggest you create a boolean `$is_found = false;` before the loop. If one row corresponds, set it to true. Then after the loop, add it only if the boolean is still `false`

Comment: @NoOorZ24  i used  !in_array($_REQUEST['tourcode'],$array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the array, check if the same values are found, and if not push the new values:

```
$tour  = $_REQUEST['tourcode'];
$promo = $_REQUEST['promocode'];

$new = true; //default to true
foreach($arrays as $el){
    if($el[0].'-'.$el[1] == $tour. '-' .$promo]){
        $new=false;
        break; //no need to continue
    }
}

if($new) $arrays[]=[$tour,$promo];
```

Comment: recode base on your solution . And it worked!! . Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrays as $key => $array) {
    if($array[0] == $_REQUEST['tourcode'] && $array[1] == $_REQUEST['promocode']) {
        unset($arrays[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is an entry with tourcode AND promocode already in the array you can use something close to what you had:

```
function codeInArray($array, $tourcode, $promocode) {
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        // check if we have an entry that has the same tour and promo code
        if ($entry[0] == $tourcode && $entry[1] == $promocode) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// run the function and see if its not in the array already
if (!codeInArray($arrays, $_GET['tourcode'], $_GET['promocode'])) {
    // add the new entry to `$arrays`
    $arrays[] = [
        $_GET['tourcode'],
        $_GET['promocode'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood changing your statement for !in_array might be the solution:

```
if (!in_array(array($_REQUEST['tourcode'],$_REQUEST['promocode']),$array))
```

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer but this one shorter and is "one-liner" so I'd suggest using this method

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = array(
  0=>array(
     0=>'VUM',
     1=>'UA0885'
  ),

  1=>array(
    0=>'VUA',
    1=>'UA0885'
  )
);

$tour_code = trim($_REQUEST['tourcode']);
$promo_code = trim($_REQUEST['promocode']); 

$filterarray = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array($tour_code , $subarray) || !in_array($promo_code , $subarray)){
            $filterarray[$counter][] = $value;
        }
    }
    $counter++;    
}
print_r($filterarray);
?>
```